# Disable body scroll when popup opens

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, popup

Im having trouble with my site. The thing is that its like a portfolio, in which you can click on a picture, and an `iframe` opens with a html5 game in it. The thing is that it is difficult to play because when you click, the body under the iframe will scroll in mobile devices. I want to block the scroll while the iframe opens. I tried putting `overflow: hidden` but it wouldnt work.
Here is the link of my webpage so you can see what my problem is:
http://kickads.mobi/richmediagallery/
Do you guys have any idea of how to do this?

Thank you!

The code for every popup is this one:

```
 <script>
document.getElementById("popup").showpopup = function() {
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('iframe').src = 
"http://kickads.mobi/test/nike/jordan/";
document.getElementById('page').className = "darken";
document.getElementById("page").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
document.getElementById("popup").showpopup();
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'hidden';
}

document.getElementById('page').onclick = function() {
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.overflow = 'visible';
if(document.getElementById("popup").style.display == "block") {
document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("page").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('page').className = "";
}
}
;</script>
```

Comment: try to implement this https://codepen.io/wesleypimentel/pen/KpgXJW

Comment: Hi, i tried, but it doesnt work in IOS. In my Iphone it still scrolls when the popup appears! I mean, the popup appears, and there is a dark layer that darkens the body, but the body beside it still scrolls